# How do I pass an array from Swift to MSL parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, swift, metal, cifilter, metal-performance-shaders

I want to make this custom CIFilter.

```
var dummyColors = [
        CIVector(x: 0.9, y: 0.3, z: 0.4),
        CIVector(x: 0.2, y: 0.5, z: 0.9),
        CIVector(x: 0.5, y: 0.9, z: 0.3)
    ]
    
    var normal = dummyColors.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (buffer) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<CIVector> in
        var p = buffer.baseAddress
        print(p)
        return p!
    }

    //this is  parameter and how to pass bvalue to the kernel function
    return self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent,
                             roiCallback: roiCallback,
                             arguments: [inputImage, reddish, greenish, blueish, normal])  // (5)
```

Here is me trying to pass parameter with pointer. However the code seem doesn't like it and it just crashed without no printing error.

And here is the metal function

```
extern "C" { namespace coreimage {               // (3)

//this is how you define parameter on the top of the function
float4 dyeInThree(sampler src,
                  float3 redVector,
                  float3 greenVector,
                  float3 blueVector,
                  device float3 *a)
```

Is there another way how to pass the parameter to my metal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adopted this answer to your use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58706038/16896928

Here's what I used for memory allocation:

```
var dummyColors = [
            SIMD3<Float>(x: 1.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1), 
            SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.1, y: 1.1, z: 0.1),
            SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 1.1)
        ]

let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(
            byteCount: 3 * MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride,
            alignment: MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.alignment)
let sPointer = dummyColors.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (buffer) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<SIMD3<Float>> in
            let p = pointer.initializeMemory(as: SIMD3<Float>.self,
            from: buffer.baseAddress!,
            count: buffer.count)
            return p
        }
let data = Data(bytesNoCopy: sPointer, count: 3 * MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride, deallocator: .free)
```

You need to convert the buffer into NSData before passing it to the kernel. And here is the Metal function declaration:

```
extern "C" { namespace coreimage {               // (3)
    float4 dyeInThree(sampler src,
                      float3 redVector,
                      float3 greenVector,
                      float3 blueVector,
                      constant float3 a[]) {
```

Note the 'constant' namespace instead of 'device'. Otherwise the Metal compiler would give error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer you get with `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is only valid inside the closure you passed to the function. You need to allocate a more "permanent" storage for the parameters.

You can start by using something like `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.allocate` to allocate the memory, but you will have to track the memory somewhere, because you will need to `deallocate` it after you are done using it.

Comment: Like this? My code still somehow doesn't work. It doesn't give the image result. I checked with just integer parameter and it still worked. It must be the parameter?
` let normal = UnsafeMutablePointer<CIVector>.allocate(capacity: dummyColors.count)
        
        //loop
        var increment = 0
        for i in dummyColors{
            (normal + increment).initialize(to: i)
            
            increment += 1
        }
        `